# How to Convert Object to list reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I call an API and get the data in object format I need that to be a list of object

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        value: 0,
        open: false,
        form: {},
        list: [],
    }
}


FillGrid() {
    const { list } = this.state;
    const newlist  = Tools.FetchSync("APP.asmx/User", {
        usrCodeFullNameStr: '', orgCodeNameStr: ''
    });
    console.log(typeof newlist)
    this.setState({list: [newlist]})
    //  alert(event.target.value+';'+res)
}
```

I need the list to make autocomplete on input, this is my `list.map`

```
<ul>
  {this.state.list.map((inputItem) => (
      <li style={{paddingTop: 30}}
      key = {inputItem.id}
      >
          {inputItem.UserInfo}
      </li>
   ))}
</ul>
```

Now my object look like this

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {usoVCodeInt: 1312, usrVCodeInt: 1122, usrNameStr: "ddd", usrFamilyStr: 
"aaaa", UserInfo: "mmmm 1", …}
1: {usoVCodeInt: 184, usrVCodeInt: 1425, usrNameStr: "ssss", usrFamilyStr: 
"xxxx", UserInfo: "vvv 990505", …}
```

I want to be something like this

```
[ {obj0}, {obj2} ]
```

so I can map that

Comment: What do you mean by **list of object** ? Can you please show an example of how do you want that

Comment: @MohammadBasit i add that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I understand the format in which your data is coming back as a response from the api. The data format can be of two types.

You can use `Object.values()` to achieve that behaviour. The `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop.

`Format type 1`

```js
var arr = []
var obj = [
 {0: {usoVCodeInt: 1312, usrVCodeInt: 1122, usrNameStr: "ddd", usrFamilyStr: 
 "aaaa", UserInfo: "mmmm 1"}},
 {1: {usoVCodeInt: 184, usrVCodeInt: 1425, usrNameStr: "ssss", usrFamilyStr: 
 "xxxx", UserInfo: "vvv 990505"}}
]

obj.forEach((ele) => {
  arr.push(Object.values(ele)[0])
})

console.log(arr)
```

`Format type 2`

```js
var obj = {
  "0": {"name": 'xyz'},
  "1": {"name": 'abc'},
  "3": {"name": 'asd'},
  "4": {"name": 'grt'}
}

console.log(Object.values(obj))
```

Hope it helps!